# Capture string from files store in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to capture string containing word "REJECTED" from set of .dat files stored in perticular folder. I am using below find command

```
find  "REJECTED" C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*
```

But it is genrating output as shown below

```
---------- C:\USERS\SBA\DESKTOP\CBS\OUTBOX\PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_11012014_47.DAT
2DR0089    C40291100002100000000628780011/01/145070A0158230-R/                         A0158230-RINR                                                                                                                                                       01  9545                                                            5070  00 BATCH REJECTED
2CR0089    G39000000033900000000628780011/01/145070A0158230-R/                         A0158230-RINR                                                                                                                                                       01  9545                                                            5070  00 BATCH REJECTED

---------- C:\USERS\SBA\DESKTOP\CBS\OUTBOX\PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_11012014_48.DAT

---------- C:\USERS\SBA\DESKTOP\CBS\OUTBOX\PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_11012014_49.DAT

---------- C:\USERS\SBA\DESKTOP\CBS\OUTBOX\PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_11012014_50.DAT
```

I dont want lines after rejected part from outpot.

```
---------- C:\USERS\SBA\DESKTOP\CBS\OUTBOX\PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_11012014_47.DAT
2DR0089    C40291100002100000000628780011/01/145070A0158230-R/                         A0158230-RINR                                                                                                                                                       01  9545                                                            5070  00 BATCH REJECTED
2CR0089    G39000000033900000000628780011/01/145070A0158230-R/                         A0158230-RINR                                                                                                                                                       01  9545                                                            5070  00 BATCH REJECTED
```

Means I want output which contains "REJECTED" only. As shown above.

How to achive this?

Comment: use `findstr` instead of `find` (use same syntax). Only disadvantage: when you use wildcard, it puts the filename before the found string

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /m /i  "REJECTED" C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*
```

The `/i` is only required for case-insensitive - if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %i in ("C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*") do @findstr "REJECTED" %i
```

for use in a batch file, use

```
for %%i in ("C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*") do findstr "REJECTED" %%i
```

EDIT:
If you want the filenames included it is even simpler:

```
findstr  "REJECTED" "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*"
```

To search in tow directories use `findstr` two times (it generates no output if nothing is found)

```
findstr  "REJECTED" "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*"
findstr  "REJECTED" "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\PROCESSED\*"
```

If you need only the names of the files that contain the string, use

```
findstr /M "REJECTED" "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*"
```

Comment: This will not list the name of the file(s) that contain the matching lines

Answer (score 0):

```
type "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*" 2>nul | find "REJECTED"
```

Only one `type` command to read all the files, sending it to only one `find` process filtering the lines. No file names and no aditional lines.

**EDITED** to adapt to comments

In the case of files being sometimes in one folder and sometimes in other, the best option is to try to `type` the files in the most usual folder, and if the command fails to find the indicated files, then type the files in the second folder (variables declaration included to shorten lines of code)

```
set "folder=C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS"
set "files=PRF_FES_ACCTBTCH_????????_*.dat"

(type "%folder%\OUTBOX\%files%" || type "%folder%\PROCESSED\%files%") 2>nul | find "REJECTED"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, type "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*" 2>nul | find "REJECTED" This works for me. can we modify like, if files(4) are not present in mention folder "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\" then these files will be at "C:\Users\SBA\Desktop\CBS\PROCESSED\" folder. How we can search same thing with above mention senario.

Comment: @user3164140: "if files(4) are not present" Does it mean that it will not be any aditional files in the folder? Or there are more files but only the 4 .dat files? What is the exact case?

Comment: @user3164140: See if the edited answer fits to your case